# Tableau: hide table calculation for only one column

Tags: hide, tableau-api

I'm working on a visualization in Tableau, regarding numbers for actual figures, budgets, and estimates. For budget and estimate, I also want to show the percentage of difference compared to the actual. I have these numbers for several categories.

I recreated an example as below.

What I now want is: Hide the percentage calculation ONLY for the actuals column. 
I tried several things. but it always ends in multiple columns being deleted. How can I do this?

(Percentages are calculated *across* table and based on "actual" scenario).

[image]

Edit 1: As in one of the answers, creating seperate calculated fields for each value is an option. But in my problem, I will have a lot of measures where I want to disply it this way. So creating 5 calculated fields for every measure is really a last option. 
Also: I now solve it using 2 different sheets on the dashboard. One sheet with actual numbers, and one sheet with percentages (hiding the actual column). But then the line up is not so nice, and also when the sorting of the dimension changes, it is tricky. I have also options to drill down the hierarchy of a dimension, and with two sheets, one of the two will of course not adapt then.

Comment: what is the condition to hide the difference for actual column?

Comment: This percentage will always be zero because you're comparing something with itself. So I don't want to show it

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using F1 for rows and F2 for columns and measures that will split to as many values as F2 has (Currently their are 3 columns).

Solution that I can think of in this particular case is to remove `F2` from columns part and create 5 formulas for the measures.

1. Actual Sum // Since we don't want Acutal (%diff) we won't create that formula
2. Budget sum
3. Budget (%Diff)
4. Estimate Sum
5. Estimate (%Diff)

Now formula will be like

```
If F2 = "Actual" //Same goes for Budget and Estimate
Then f3
End
```

Take one more sheet now add the quick table calculation for difference for Budget and Estimate and add those to Formula fields.

Now place all 5 formulas in columns part, So you have your measures.

To add the column headings you can use dashboard, Add the sheet to dashboard and manually add texts to the measures that will look like the one you have attached in screen shot.

I have implemented a sample using `Sample super store` and attaching the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: This is actually a perfect solution which I have used before. But the problem is that I have way more measures where I have to do this. So if it would be for only 1 measure, it would be perfect. In my case, I might have >20 measures, so creating 5 formula's for all of them is not something I would like to do.. I'll edit my question to include this. Thanks for your effort anyway!